# How to get response header of a solr query in solrnet?

Tags: c#, solr, solrnet

How do I get the response header variables like `qtime, no.of docs found, etc.` for a particular `Solr` query in `solrnet`. I assume I need to touch `ResponseHeader.cs.` Please provide any Solutions !

Comment: Could you provide more description on what you have tried till now and what is the research you done for it. what type of system you are using? which version of Solr, etc.

Comment: Actually i got what i want ! I'm using Solr 4.3.1.
a simple  query is
var q=solr.query("Electronics");

the above query returns some results with qtime and number of docs found. i want to get qtime. 

so i tried sometime like this

q.Header.QTime; it worked . it is the thing which i was looking for .

Comment: Can you update the question and give your answer as the accepted answer?